# Pydev and system sys.path

Tags: pydev

I'm running Python scripts from at least two sources:

- Pydev in Eclipse
- python.exe

on MS Windows. MS Windows provides pythonwin.exe, which allows python path permanent configuration.

When I do:

- modify the system path in Pythonwin
- restart Eclipse

The new sys.path **is** reflected in Pydev.
I'm not sure, but Pydev documentation says the opposite:

> What if I add something new in my System PYTHONPATH after configuring it?
>
> If you add something to your python installation, you need to either
>   add it manually as a 'new folder' in the System PYTHONPATH (if it's still > not under a folder in the PYTHONPATH)
>   or (recommended) remove your interpreter and add it again, then, press apply.
>
> Note that if you added a library that's already under a folder in the PYTHONPATH, you have to at least go to
>   the interpreter preferences and press apply so that it clears its internal caches (
>   **after the configuration is done, things are set in stone for PyDev**
>   ) "

The question is - can I rely on present behaviour? Can I enable/disable it? Is my understanding of the documentation correct?

Pydev revision: newest (3.9 IIRC)
Eclipe revision: Luna

Regards,
Robert